# Android XML Parsing: Parse this special Type of XML i have no Idia about this

Tags: java, php, android, xml, xml-parsing

This is XML URL

http://www.eboundservices.com/distribution/vod_new.xml

How we Parse in Android

```
<Aajkamrankhankaysath p0201="" p0801="" p0901="" p1501="" p1601="" p2201="" p2301="" p2901="" p3001="" p0702="" p2102="" p0303="" p0403="" p0603="" p1003="" p1103="" p1203="" p1303="" p1703="" p1803="" p1903="" p2003="" p2403="" p2503="" p2603="" p2703="" p2803="" p3103="" p0104="" p0204="" p0304="" p0404="" p0704="" p0804="" p0904="" p1004="" p1104="" p1404="" p1504="" p1604="" p1704="" p1804="" p2104="" p2204="" p2304="" p2404="" p2804="" p2904="" p3004="" p0105="" p0205="" p0505="" p0605="" p0705="" p0805="" p0905="" p1205="" p1305="" p1405="" p1505="" p1605="" p1905="" p2005="" p2105="" p2205="" p2305="" p2705="" p2805="" p2905="" p3005="" p0206="" p0306="" p0406="" p0506="" p2306="" p2406="" p2506="">25</Aajkamrankhankaysath>
```

I want to get like: p0201, p0801, p0901, p1501, p1501... and So On

I want to save in ArrayList, mean A TAG <>  data in a AaaryList Respectively

Comment: That has to be the worst format XML I've ever seen. The various parts you want (such as p0201, p0801 etc) are XML 'attributes'. Do you have any control over the server / data source? If so then I suggest you change the way the data is presented (JSON perhaps).

Comment: Thanks @Squonk 
there is no way to parse this type of XML mean get Attributes like p0201, p0801, p0901, p1501, p1501...

Comment: @Squonk 
http://www.eboundservices.com
the eboundservices is not a small service and it is Possible I think :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all these are attributes as someone has already mentioned. It is certainly a bad idea to have such a badly formed XML, even if the web-service is big I can see it's being developed in a very bad manner. Personal opinions aside, you will need to create your own class in order to populate a list of objects. You will need to read through every node, and populate every attribute manually and no short cut will work(as far as I know).

```
public class TVNode {
    String p0210;
    String p0801;
    String p0901;

    // so on an so forth, define String mmembers for every attribute
    public TVNode()
    {

    }

    public void setp0210(String _p0210)
    {
    }
    public void setp0801(String _p0801)
    {
    }
    public void setp0901(String _p0901)
    {
    }
    // and getters too of course    
}
```

You'll have a list of TVNode type, you'll read the XML from either a file or web-response and once you have it you'll need to parse it using some type of XMLDOMParser. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

xmlpullparser is faster than loading a document.  It is exactly suited for the xml example you have in your question.

```
        XmlPullParser xpp;
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = null;

        factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        xpp = factory.newPullParser();
        xpp.setInput(kmlis, "UTF-8");  //todo get your input into inputstream


        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while (true) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                if (xpp.getName().equals("aajdsaklhandsksplsb")){
                 int x = xpp.getAttributeCount();
                  for (int i = 0;i<x;i++){
                      String name = xpp.getAttributeName(i);
                      String value = xpp.getAttributeValue(i)
                       log.d("test", name + "=" + value);
                  }

                 }
            }
             else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {break;}

         eventType = xpp.getEventType();
         }
```

Comment: After looking at your link you'll have to finess the start_tag to get the name of the node then go through the little loop to get out all the attributes for that name.

Answer (score 0):

That has to be the worst format XML, there a some other parser like **XMLPullParser, DOMParser and SAXParser** but you can use **xmlPullParser** to get attribute values according to your requirements.

Here is sample xml:

```
<message id="abc@web.hightech.com" from="web.hightect.com" text="Hello World">
<firstname>Marie Josèphe</firstname>
<lastname>Joseph</lastname>
</message>
```

Here is a complete Parser and you can use this generic parser to fulfill your requirement
Example: You can to get id and text from first attribute

```
    public class New_Generic_Parser {
    public static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject = null;
    String payload,option_text1,option_text2;

    public New_Generic_Parser() {
    payload = "";
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    option_text1 = "";
    option_text2 = "";
    }

    private void parseXMLAndStoreIt(XmlPullParser myParser) {
    int event;
    try {
    event = myParser.getEventType();
    while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
    String name=myParser.getName();
    switch (event){
    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
    if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("user")){
    option_text1 = myParser.getAttributeValue(null, "id");
    option_text2 = myParser.getAttributeValue(null,"text");
    //get attribute from here:
    }
     break;
    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
        if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("user")){
            list.add(myParser.getText());
        }
   break;
   case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
      String pic = list.get(0).toString();
      byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(pic,Base64.DEFAULT);
      Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
   break;
   }         
   event = myParser.next(); 
 }
//    parsingComplete = false;
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
    }
    public void genericparser(String payload){
    try {
         InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(payload.getBytes());
         xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
         XmlPullParser myparser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();
         myparser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
         myparser.setInput(stream, null);
         parseXMLAndStoreIt(myparser);
         stream.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
   }
```